# php pdo count same column and display just one row

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following code:

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM penjualan";
    $stmt = $con->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
        extract($row);
?>
<?php echo $penjualan_kode;?>  
<?php endwhile;?>
```

And the output looks like this

```
JL1202146
JL1202146
JL1202146
JL1202149
JL1202149
```

But I want it to be like this:

```
JL1202146 (3)
JL1202149 (2)
```

How can i do that?
Or can you give me a link or something so I can learn?

UPDATE 1 :

I got other error here the code

```
  <?php
      $queryqq = "SELECT * FROM `penjualan`";
      $queryqq = "SELECT COUNT(penjualan_kode) AS hitung, penjualan_kode FROM penjualan GROUP BY penjualan_kode";
    $stmtq = $con->prepare( $queryqq );
    $stmtq->execute();
    $numq = $stmtq->rowCount();
    if($numq>0):
    while ($rowq = $stmtq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
    extract($rowq);
     @$z++;
  ?>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo $z;?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <code><?php echo $penjualan_kode;?></code>
    </td> 
    <td>
        <?php echo $penjualan_tgl;?> // here is line 50 in error
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $hitung;?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $z;?>
    </td>
  </tr> 
  <?php
    endwhile;
    endif;
  ?>
```

and error is like this

> Notice: Undefined variable: penjualan_tgl in /var/www/me/stok/penjualan.php on line 50

how to fix that?

Comment: well, its more of knowing sql statements rather than PDO firstly.. this might help:: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/counting-rows.html

Comment: You can't do this `$queryqq = "SELECT * FROM..."; $queryqq = "SELECT COUNT(penjualan_kode)...` - It's one or the other.

Comment: can you post the corect code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using:

```
SELECT COUNT(column_name) as column_count, column_name FROM penjualan GROUP BY column_name
```

I've created a SQL Fiddle example for you:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f3938/1

I'd suggest you have a read of the MySQL Manual on it's `GROUP BY` functions

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: Thanks dude @ajtrichards. i was edit my code in update 1. but I got error, can you give me sugestion how to fix that?

Comment: Have you set the variable called `$penjualan_tgl`? @3118731

Comment: in my db $penjualan_tgl is like this `2014-02-12 00:00:00` .
i dont know much about php or mysql..